# MS Access 2013: Multiple contacts

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I am pretty new to access so I've been encountering multiple issues with my project. I would appreciate any help/guidance that I can get.

Comment: I think error is clear. There is a syntax error. But unfortunately, without knowing how you've setup your fields, tables and links between table, it would be difficult to diagnose the problem. However, I would suggest not to use the forms in Access. Try using Excel VBA to connect to your database. Firstly excel has "true" forms and second, accessing your database via excel will give you the security that no one has direct access to your database

Comment: Without going into too much detail, Excel forms are actual forms as you would get in a development environment (i.e. as you would see in Visual Studio). Access forms ... well, in the most simplest and blunt term, its a window that is painted to look like a form. I Guess its like butter and margarine, it might look like butter .. but its not butter :). There are lots of examples of it, just do a search on google if you want to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

The only possible type mismatch there is the Data type of `ID` which right now, we would both assume is a number. But it in fact ID is most probably a `ShortText` data type.

To cut it short, adjust your where clause as follows:
[image: Where Clause Macro]

Or in your case:

```
 ="ID='" & [Screen].[ActiveControl] & "'"
```